# Wrong variable/value for my product image

Tags: product

I have some code, and somehow, I not get the product image in this part of my code:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())
```

How I can check and test, that here is my product image. I did already var dump's for the array `$_product` and `$_image` and I see there all the times the image as an value.

Here is one part of the dump of $_product:

```
["_cacheTag":protected]=>
  string(15) "catalog_product"
  ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
  string(15) "catalog_product"
  ["_eventObject":protected]=>
  string(7) "product"
  ["_canAffectOptions":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_typeInstance":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_typeInstanceSingleton":protected]=>
  object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable)#267 (15) {
    ["_usedProductAttributeIds":protected]=>
    string(42) "_cache_instance_used_product_attribute_ids"
    ["_usedProductAttributes":protected]=>
    string(39) "_cache_instance_used_product_attributes"
    ["_usedAttributes":protected]=>
    string(31) "_cache_instance_used_attributes"
    ["_configurableAttributes":protected]=>
    string(39) "_cache_instance_configurable_attributes"
    ["_usedProductIds":protected]=>
    string(27) "_cache_instance_product_ids"
    ["_usedProducts":protected]=>
    string(24) "_cache_instance_products"
    ["_isComposite":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_canConfigure":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_product":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_typeId":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_setAttributes":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_editableAttributes":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_canUseQtyDecimals":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_storeFilter":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_fileQueue":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["_linkInstance":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_customOptions":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_urlModel":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_errors":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_optionInstance":protected]=>
  object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option)#282 (19) {
    ["_product":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_options":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_valueInstance":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_values":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
    string(13) "core_abstract"
    ["_eventObject":protected]=>
    string(6) "object"
    ["_resourceName":protected]=>
    string(22) "catalog/product_option"
    ["_resource":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=>
    string(33) "catalog/product_option_collection"
    ["_cacheTag":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_isObjectNew":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_data":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_origData":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["_options":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_reservedAttributes":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_isDuplicable":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_calculatePrice":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_defaultValues":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_storeValuesFlags":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_lockedAttributes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_isDeleteable":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_isReadonly":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_resourceName":protected]=>
  string(15) "catalog/product"
  ["_resource":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=>
  string(26) "catalog/product_collection"
  ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_isObjectNew":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(74) {
    ["store_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(5) "65848"
    ["entity_type_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["attribute_set_id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["type_id"]=>
    string(12) "configurable"
    ["sku"]=>
    string(9) "L36676800"
    ["has_options"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["required_options"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(25) "2015-11-09T10:10:50-05:00"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2015-10-08 10:52:25"
    ["name"]=>
    string(54) "Salomon Men's XA Pro 3D Waterproof Trail Running Shoes"
    ["meta_title"]=>
    NULL
    ["meta_description"]=>
    NULL
    ["image"]=>
    string(38) "/i/m/image_81sGl8PMUcL._UL1500__11.jpg"
    ["small_image"]=>
    string(38) "/i/m/image_81sGl8PMUcL._UL1500__11.jpg"
    ["thumbnail"]=>
    string(38) "/i/m/image_81sGl8PMUcL._UL1500__11.jpg"
    ["gallery"]=>
    NULL
    ["url_key"]=>
    string(54) "salomon-men-s-xa-pro-3d-waterproof-trail-running-shoes"
    ["url_path"]=>
    string(59) "salomon-men-s-xa-pro-3d-waterproof-trail-running-shoes.html"
    ["custom_design"]=>
    NULL
    ["page_layout"]=>
    NULL
    ["options_container"]=>
    string(10) "container1"
    ["image_label"]=>
    NULL
    ["small_image_label"]=>
    NULL
    ["thumbnail_label"]=>
    NULL
    ["country_of_manufacture"]=>
    NULL
    ["msrp_enabled"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["msrp_display_actual_price_type"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["gift_message_available"]=>
    NULL
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "144.9500"
    ["special_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["minimal_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["msrp"]=>
    NULL
    ["manufacturer"]=>
    string(3) "744"
    ["old_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "2907"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["visibility"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["tax_class_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["featured"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["size"]=>
    NULL
```

And here the var dump from $_image:

o

```
bject(Varien_Object)#1001 (7) {
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(12) {
    ["value_id"]=>
    string(5) "72744"
    ["file"]=>
    string(38) "/i/m/image_81sGl8PMUcL._UL1500__11.jpg"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(5) "65848"
    ["label"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["disabled"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["label_default"]=>
    NULL
    ["position_default"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["disabled_default"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url"]=>
    string(91) "https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/media/catalog/product/i/m/image_81sGl8PMUcL._UL1500__11.jpg"
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "72744"
    ["path"]=>
    string(80) "/srv/htdocs/html/mag/media/catalog/product/i/m/image_81sGl8PMUcL._UL1500__11.jpg"
  }
  ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_origData":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

What I see in the exception log:

```
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Memory limit has been reached.' in /srv/htdocs/html/mag/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:58
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/htdocs/html/mag/lib/Varien/Image.php(70): Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2->open('/srv/htdocs/htm...')
#1 /srv/htdocs/html/mag/lib/Varien/Image.php(52): Varien_Image->open()
#2 /srv/htdocs/html/mag/app/code/community/SMDesign/Colorswatch/Helper/Images.php(100): Varien_Image->__construct('/srv/htdocs/htm...')
#3 /srv/htdocs/html/mag/app/design/frontend/smartwave/legenda/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml(86): SMDesign_Colorswatch_Helper_Images->resize()
```

Comment: Are you able to post the dump of the `$_product` and `$_image`

Comment: Can you disable your `SMDesign_Colorswatch` extension and see if that is causing it.

Comment: The situation if I disable the SMDesign Colorswatch is the follow on one of those examples:

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/active/salomon-men-s-xa-pro-3d-waterproof-trail-running-shoes.html

Here You have sizes:

If disabled, I am able to choose from the sizes.
If it enabled, I can't choose from the sizes

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get image:

```
<img id="image-main"
        itemprop="image"
         class="gallery-image visible"
         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail') ?>"/>
```

This will show image. If you want to check if product image exist, then try this:

```
<?php if($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')){
     echo "Image exist.";
?>
```

I haven't tested the `if` condition part, but should work.

Assumption, `$_product` is a `product` object and it is predefined.

Comment: This tried, and I get an image there (Image exist).

Comment: Great, does it answers your question?

Comment: No, not directly...

Comment: Have you configured in admin area? http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/646771/c0599a7f72856814152bcec49ef043e4 You have to set product for each image type.

Comment: Yes, they are.
The issue is, around 3 days ago, it worked. Just happend somehow that it not worked again.
And I not see any product images on hole page.

Comment: Did you clear the cache and index. Also is your compilation turned on?

Comment: You mention refresh the cache and reindex?
To turn the compilation on? How to?
Compilation is disabled. What exactly happens if I turn it on? Possible to have a "fallback" is something goes wrong?

Comment: To refresh your cache, go to your "System > Cache management" and then clear all the cache. To reindex, "System > index management" and reindex all.

Comment: how to refresh and reindex I know. Can do some reindex in the ssh session.
I am afraid to do the compilation on, if something goes wrong...

Comment: no no, don't turn compilation on if you don't need it. If you have installed some extension while compilation was on then it may had problem.

Answer (score 1):

To get the image try:

```
<?php if ($_product->getImage() != 'no_selection' && $_product->getImage()): ?>
    <?php
        $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will check to make sure the image is available plus the helper `$_helper->productAttribute` process the field.

See `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

Comment: Hi rob3000

I still get the standard default image:

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/active/salomon-men-s-xa-pro-3d-waterproof-trail-running-shoes.html

Comment: Ok, so what image are you trying to get? You might want to adjust your question a little.

Comment: I am trying to get the product image. But somehow this not works.

Could it be casue some problem with caching the image, when Magento likes to resize the image?

And then it takes the standart image instead of...

Comment: Magento will cache the image when it resizes it, but the above code should work if your trying to get the normal product image. In saying that is this a simple product or configurable product? Also checking on that url, does the image exist? its returning a 404 for `https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/i/m/image_81sGl8PMUcL._UL1500__11.jpg`

Comment: Yes, the image not exist there:

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/media/catalog/product/i/m/image_81sGl8PMUcL._UL1500__11.jpg

Comment: Try uploading it again.

Answer (score 0):

thank You for Your help. I found finally this article:

http://www.sangaytenzin.com/magento-1-8-bug-memory-limit-has-been-reached/

And I changed the Gd2.php as describe in this article. And it works now.

I am sure it is not the final version or final step. But I am also guessing, that our images are all too big.

Kindly